# How to use Activity on navigation drawer insted of fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I am working in app where i use navigation drawer but all of them are in fragments some of them are in activity but don't works properly.

- My Question is that how to use **navigation drawer for activities** just like fragment attached and detached.
- Here [**example tabhost**](http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/android-viewflipper-within-tabhost-for-tabs-with-different-views-and-better-memory/) where same technique that i want in navigation
  drawer

Any tutorial help or any suggestion, i will be thankful for that..

```
tabHost = getTabHost();
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_one));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_two));
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Comment: One way I can think of is, by placing one activity on top of another with some margin left value assigned to the activity on top.

Comment: thanks @stack_ved but how can do like this